# Getting exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while using json-schema-validator-2.2.6

Tags: java, json, validation, json-schema-validator

I am trying to use the `json-schema` validator on the code given in [this link](http://wildiary.com/validate-json-against-schema-in-java) using eclipse..

There is a main class which reads the two `.json` file(schema and json data)
if `(ValidationUtils.isJsonValid(schemaFile, jsonFile))` is used to validate them a `ValidationUtils` class which takes the schema file and the json file and validates it..

but i am getting the following errors.. and i donno how to fix it..plz help?

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/github/fge/msgsimple/bundle/PropertiesBundle  at
>   com.github.fge.jackson.JsonNodeReader.(JsonNodeReader.java:66)
>     at com.github.fge.jackson.JsonLoader.(JsonLoader.java:50)   at
>   com.wilddiary.json.ValidationUtils.getJsonNode(ValidationUtils.java:30)
>     at
>   com.wilddiary.json.ValidationUtils.getSchemaNode(ValidationUtils.java:55)
>     at
>   com.wilddiary.json.ValidationUtils.isJsonValid(ValidationUtils.java:99)
>     at com.wilddiary.json.Main.main(Main.java:18) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.github.fge.msgsimple.bundle.PropertiesBundle  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   ... 6 more

i'm using:

- json-schema-validator-2.2.6
- json-schema-core-1.2.5
- jackson coreutils 1.8
- jackson databind 2.7.2
- jackson annotations 2.7.2
- com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception implies that class `com.github.fge.msgsimple.bundle.PropertiesBundle` is not present on your run-time class-path. To fix this problem you should download msg-simple-0.9.jar (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.fge/msg-simple/0.9) and put it into your class-path.